# How much reputation do I need to suggest a tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I was trying to ask a question, but the tag I wanted to use doesn't exist. How can I suggest a new tag?

I want to make this tag, but I think my reputation is not high enough to suggest a tag. How can I still suggest one to Stack Overflow in such a situation?

Comment: What was the tag you wanted to create?

Comment: I wanted to create a tag with PSPP, which is a substitute of SPSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SO
[image: SO]
Meta
[image: MetaOverflow]

Comment: @Krishnabhadra is answering for 1500 Rep, I am confused now

Comment: 1500 rep for Stack Overflow, 500 for Meta Stack Overflow. Those are different sites @StarGazer

Comment: @StarGazer no need. The reputation needed is different for stackoverflow.com and meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Oh.., Thanks for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 4):

To create tags you need 1500 reputation.

See [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) page for details. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) is the information about creating tags.

Comment: 500 or 1500 Rep.

Comment: For stackoverflow 1500..